# can't load images from different directory in Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

This problem might be about permission but I don't know how to fix this

my structure is like this :

```
  public_html/
   ➥ foto_produk/ (this where I store the images)
      alpha/ (this where my subdomain files are)
       ➥ thing.php
```

now the html to load the images

```
  <?php
   echo"<img src='../foto_produk/image.jpg'/>";
   ?>
```

the images are loaded successfully in localhost but not in cpanel hosting. 
and when I try changing permission for foto_produk folder it is already readable by user group and world, or do I need to check all of the options?

[image]

when I try inspecting the console, URL is pointing to subdomain directory
 `subdomains/foto_produk/images file` instead of main domain directory

[image]

Comment: try to write only `echo"<img src='foto_produk/image.jpg'/>";`
Or just give the full link for this issue

Comment: hi. that would be using the folder from subdomain, I want to store all images of 'produk' in 1 folder in main domain, hence I'm trying to find a way to load the images on main domain from subdomain

Comment: http://alpha.rajafotocopy.com/ << here the link to my problem

Answer (score 0):

never mind I got this.

just need to write main domain URL before /foto_produk

`echo"<img src='maindomain.com/foto_produk/image.jpg'/>";`

I don't think this is the best solution.... if there are other solution better than this please share the answer